# Duplicate geometry by inheriting features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, lizmap

I'm working with QGIS desktop and then exporting the project to Lizmap.
What I need to do is modify the attributes of an already existing point geometry:
For example I have a point geometry with various attributes ( x,y,z , for example)
I would like to add a new row that has the same geometry but with some fields changed.
Lizmap has the function of adding features, but I would have to place the editor on the existing geometry and write all the fields manually.
Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: It is not possible to duplicate a feature in Lizmap but it would be a nice enhancement. You can ask for this feature here and it will be developed when funded : https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement&projects=&template=2_Feature_request.md&title=

Comment: Do you mean to duplicate the geometry in QGIS or in Lizmap. The question title implies in QGIS.

Comment: In QGIS I know it can be done. I imagined that we could work in the attributes field with some Python function in order to find the feature also in Lizmap

Comment: Maybe change the title then?